# Condition before HasOne, BelongsTo relation

Tags: laravel, relation

I got a problem when writing a single relation method with laravel project.

I have 2 table:

- **residents** with columns: `id`, `building_id`, `phone`. `building_id` and `phone` have an unique constraint
- **services** with columns: `id`, `building_id`, `phone`. `building_id` and `phone` don't have an unique constraint

I have a method get resident from service model:

```php
public function resident()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Resident::class, 'phone', 'phone');
}
```

When I have residents with same `phone` but difference `building_id`, resident returned from relation is incorrect. I've tried adding `where` clause to relation

```php
public function resident()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Resident::class, 'phone', 'phone')
        ->where('building_id', $this->building_id);
}
```

But it return `null`. It seems `where` clause is run after `belongsTo` relation executed.

I also got a solution by adding condition when using eager-loading:

```php
Service::where('building_id', $buildingId)
    ->with(['resident' => fn ($query) => $query->where('building_id', $buildingId)])
    ->get();
```

In this way, I can get correct resident I want. But whenever I get resident from service, I must using eager-loading query to do that. Is there a way to do this in `resident` method?

Comment: have you tried `dd()`-ing `$this->building_id`?

Comment: I just have check it, it returned `null`. I tried replace `$this->building_id` with fixed value and it returned correct value. I wonder why `$this->building_id` return `null` value, because I used this before and `building_id` always has value in database. May be it because of eager-loading?

Comment: Most likely no. Can you make sure `building_id` was not inside `$hidden` array on your model?

Comment: Yeah, I even don't declare `$hidden` in model. But according to this article (https://www.py4u.net/discuss/62508), it seems it cannot pass params to relation if you're using earger-loading

Comment: I also tried get `resident` without eager-loading and `$this->building_id` got correct value of correspond to `service`

Comment: Have you tried `dd()`-ing other properties?

Comment: other properties also return `null`. I also tried `dd($this->attributes)`, it returned an empty array